# c# split string in 2. letter by letter

Tags: c#, string, split

I need split my string in 2, one letter to each variable.

Example: string = "ABCDEFGHIJ"
name1: ACEGI
name2: BDFHJ

I done so far:

```
        var builderM = new StringBuilder();
        var builderK = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            builderM.Append(s[i]);
            builderK.Append(s[i++]);
        }

        txtM.Text = builderM.ToString();
        txtK.Text = builderK.ToString();
```

But its showing same text in the 2.

Comment: if string size is odd, the code will throw index out of range exception, you could simply add another check on length before ```builderK.Append(s[++i]);```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `++i` instead of `i++`

```
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        builderM.Append(s[i]);
        if(i + 1 < s.Length) // to prevent IOR exception when count is odd.
             builderK.Append(s[++i]); // pre increment.
    }
```

the reason is that `i++` is post incremented. that means `i` gets incremented after the expression therefor `s[i++]` will give you same item as `s[i]`.

Comment: It´s work when i enter "ABCD", but if i put just 3 letters "ABD", trows a error in the ++i line. Tnks for the help, friend.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use LINQ to filter odd and even indices into two strings, something like:

```
var even = new string(input.Where((c, idx) => idx % 2 == 0).ToArray());
var odd = new string(input.Where((c, idx) => idx % 2 != 0).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the modulus operator (`%`) to determine if the index is even or odd, and put the even indexes in the first array and the odd indexes in the second one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0) builderM.Append(s[i]);
    else builderK.Append(s[i]);
}
```

If you'd rather increment the `i` inside the `for` body, you have to repeat the check against `s.Length` (as we do in the `for` condition). Also, you will need to either move the post-increment to the previous line (so that `i` is incremented in time), or use a pre-increment:

```
// Move post-increment to previous line example:
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    builderM.Append(s[i++]);
    if (i < s.Length) builderK.Append(s[i]);
}

// Use a pre-increment example:
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    builderM.Append(s[i]);
    if (++i < s.Length) builderK.Append(s[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not an issue, you can use LINQ:

```
    var name1 = String.Join(String.Empty, str.Where((v, i) => i % 2 == 0));
    var name2 = String.Join(String.Empty, str.Where((v, i) => i % 2 == 1));
```

Comment: Hi, 2 questions: why a `string.Join`? And, why the performance remark?

Comment: `string.join` is equivalent of `toarray`, regarding performance, there are two loops (`where`) with LINQ instead of one if he used a simple for loop